# Line-height does not seem to work inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have been unable to get a table to format fonts like the one in the image.  What I did was to set the line-height for numbers to 33% but thus far the line height has always been a full line height and I would not be able to get the below layout using either table tag or div/span tags.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/vmedg/

There's different ways to achieve the look of that pic. I'll provide you with an example to get started.

I prefer using `position: absolute` since it's much easier to arrange `N` boxes in `1` container. Sometimes, it might be pretty impossible without using it. `position: absolute` fixes the element `div` to the parent element `.container`.

So by setting the `.letter` to `top: 0` and  `left: 0` , it positions it starting at the top left. But you want the letter to expand the whole container like in your pic. So to do that we can simply add `bottom: 0` to force it to stretch the whole way.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
    <div class="number one">1</div>
    <div class="number two">2</div>
    <div class="number three">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: silver;  //remove this to make it white like in your pic
}
.letter {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;        
    top: 0;
    width: 80%;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 248px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
.number {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 19%;
    height: 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-indent: 15px;
}
.one {
    top: 0;
}
.two {
    top: 33%;
}
.three {
    top: 66%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Do you know what I can do to prevent next alphabet to start a new line?  I would like to have at least a few of the alphabets in each line.

Comment: Got it working with using "float: left;".  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You an change the font size and borders accordingly, but the following layout should work

```
<div style="display:inline-block;font-size:400%">A</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am still playing with your suggestion and the suggestion from AlienArrays to see which one formats better when I use Chinses words instead of alphabets.

Comment: Your answer also worked for me, I really wish I could mark more than one responses as answers.  Thank you.